# How to set the focus to a textbox when a jquery dialog is loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

When I am executing the below line, the dialog is opening properly.

```
$('#divMyDialogBox').dialog('open');
```

But I have a textbox (i.e txtAddr) inside the div (dialog box) & want the focus to be prompted, when it's going to be loaded.

I tried the below code but it's not working. Please rectify the same or suggest new solutions.

```
        $('#divEmailDialogBox').dialog
        ({
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            hide: 'slide',
            show: 'slide',
            height: 100,
            width: 575,
            bgiframe: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            zIndex: 9999,
            open: function(){alert("Hi"); $("#txtAddr").focus();}
        });

    <%if(true)
    {%>
               $('#divEmailDialogBox').dialog('open');
    <%}
```

Here alert is firing, indicates the code is getting called.

Thanks in Advance,
Biki

Answer (score 0):

Does your function get called at all? Does it get called before or after the dialog appears? (You can change the `focus` call with an `alert` to find out).

Have you tried using the dialog's `focus` event instead of the `open` event?

Comment: Edited my post as per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Best to make sure there is no other textbox on the page with the same ID. Can you paste your HTML here please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your current show with this:

`show: { effect: 'slide', complete: function() { $(this).find("#txtaddr").focus(); }},`

This should work for Jquery UI 1.8.4+